# Concat returns The nested query is not supported. Operation1='UnionAll' Operation2='MultiStreamNest'

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a query, which looks like this:

```
ProviderNotes.Where(it=>it.NoteEntityId == 272651).Select(it=>new
{
    Id = it.NoteId,
    Tags = it.ProviderNoteTags.Select(t => t.RelatedEntityId)
}).Concat(BookingNotes.Where(it=>it.NoteEntityId == 272651).Select(it=>new
{
    Id = it.NoteId,
    Tags = it.BookingNoteTags.Select(t => t.RelatedEntityId)
}
))
```

and when I'm trying to get results of it, I'm getting

> The nested query is not supported.
>   Operation1='UnionAll' Operation2='MultiStreamNest'

There are 2 restrictions on that query:
1) I can't get each query as IEnumerable before combining that, because I need it in IQueryable form for further filterings
2) I can't populate inner collection by separate query, because each query that is being concatenated, is being formed in different repo with different tables

P.S. The example I provided I tested in LinqPad. It is really simplified to provide the idea of what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

> because each query that is being concatenated, is being formed in different repo with different tables

If the tables are in a different repository, how on earth do you expect LINQ to be able to turn it into a single query?

The only place that the two repositories meet is in your LINQ code. Therefore your LINQ code **MUST** realize the intermediate results. There is no alternative.

Comment: I didn't probably explain correctly. These tables are in the same context. Both parent and child table have the same structure, the only difference is that on db level it's different tables. I have a base class which forms query for certain table, and than I have repos, which are just config classes inherited from this base one, just specifying concrete tables. Why I can't use intermediate results is that after union I have to apply paging filter, so I don't select 10k records to show just 5 on screen. And btw, without inner query for tags everything works ok.